# Array.Sort() performance drop when sorting class instances instead of floats

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, sorting

Array.Sort in C# is really fast if you sort floats, I need some extra data to go along with those floats so I made a simple class and extended the IComparable interface. Now all of a sudden Array.Sort is around 3-4 times slower, why is this and how can I improve the performance?

Demo code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace SortTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arraySize = 10000;
            int loops = 500;

            double normalFloatTime = 0;
            double floatWithIDTime = 0;
            double structTime = 0;
            double arraySortOverloadTime = 0;

            bool floatWithIDCorrect = true;
            bool structCorrect = true;
            bool arraySortOverloadCorrect = true;

            //just so we know the program is busy
            Console.WriteLine("Sorting random arrays, this will take some time...");

            Random random = new Random();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                float[] normalFloatArray = new float[arraySize];
                SortTest[] floatWithIDArray = new SortTest[arraySize];
                SortStruct[] structArray = new SortStruct[arraySize];
                SortTest[] arraySortOverloadArray = new SortTest[arraySize];

                //fill the arrays
                for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
                {
                    normalFloatArray[j] = NextFloat(random);
                    floatWithIDArray[j] = new SortTest(normalFloatArray[j], j);
                    structArray[j] = new SortStruct(normalFloatArray[j], j);
                    arraySortOverloadArray[j] = new SortTest(normalFloatArray[j], j);
                }

                //Reset stopwatch from any previous state
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                Array.Sort(normalFloatArray);
                sw.Stop();
                normalFloatTime += sw.ElapsedTicks;

                //Reset stopwatch from any previous state
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                Array.Sort(floatWithIDArray);
                sw.Stop();
                floatWithIDTime += sw.ElapsedTicks;

                //Reset stopwatch from any previous state
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                Array.Sort(structArray);
                sw.Stop();
                structTime += sw.ElapsedTicks;

                //Reset stopwatch from any previous state
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                Array.Sort(arraySortOverloadArray.Select(k => k.ID).ToArray(), arraySortOverloadArray);
                sw.Stop();
                arraySortOverloadTime += sw.ElapsedTicks;

                for (int k = 0; k < normalFloatArray.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (normalFloatArray[k] != floatWithIDArray[k].SomeFloat)
                    {
                        floatWithIDCorrect = false;
                    }

                    if (normalFloatArray[k] != structArray[k].SomeFloat)
                    {
                        structCorrect = false;
                    }

                    if (normalFloatArray[k] != arraySortOverloadArray[k].SomeFloat)
                    {
                        arraySortOverloadCorrect = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            //calculate averages
            double normalFloatAverage = normalFloatTime / loops;
            double floatWithIDAverage = floatWithIDTime / loops;
            double structAverage = structTime / loops;
            double arraySortOverloadAverage = arraySortOverloadTime / loops;

            //print averages
            Console.WriteLine("normalFloatAverage: {0} ticks.\nfloatWithIDAverage: {1} ticks.\nstructAverage: {2} ticks.\narraySortOverloadAverage: {3} ticks.", normalFloatAverage, floatWithIDAverage, structAverage, arraySortOverloadAverage);

            Console.WriteLine("floatWithIDArray has " + (floatWithIDCorrect ? "" : "NOT ") + "been sorted correctly atleast once.");
            Console.WriteLine("structArray has " + (structCorrect ? "" : "NOT ") + "been sorted correctly atleast once.");
            Console.WriteLine("arraySortOverloadArray has " + (arraySortOverloadCorrect ? "" : "NOT ") + "been sorted correctly atleast once.");

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            //pause so we can see the console
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static float NextFloat(Random random)
        {
            double mantissa = (random.NextDouble() * 2.0) - 1.0;
            double exponent = Math.Pow(2.0, random.Next(-126, 128));
            return (float)(mantissa * exponent);
        }
    }

    class SortTest : IComparable<SortTest>
    {
        public float SomeFloat;
        public int ID;

        public SortTest(float f, int id)
        {
            SomeFloat = f;
            ID = id;
        }

        public int CompareTo(SortTest other)
        {
            float f = other.SomeFloat;
            if (SomeFloat < f)
                return -1;
            else if (SomeFloat > f)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    struct SortStruct : IComparable<SortStruct>
    {
        public float SomeFloat;
        public int ID;

        public SortStruct(float f, int id)
        {
            SomeFloat = f;
            ID = id;
        }

        public int CompareTo(SortStruct other)
        {
            float f = other.SomeFloat;
            if (SomeFloat < f)
                return -1;
            else if (SomeFloat > f)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo output:

```
Sorting random arrays, this will take some time...
normalFloatAverage: 3840,998 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 12850.672 ticks.
Press enter to exit.
```

---

**Edit**: I updated the code to also sort using a struct and a delegate, as suggested below, there is no difference.

New demo output:

```
Sorting random arrays, this will take some time...
normalFloatAverage: 3629.092 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 12721.622 ticks.
structAverage: 12870.584 ticks.
Press enter to exit.
```

---

**Edit 2**: I have updated my code with some of the suggestions below, making it a struct either has no effect on my pc or I am doing something horribly wrong. I also added some sanity checks.

New demo output (don't let the "atleast once" fool you, it is misphrased):

```
Sorting random arrays, this will take some time...
normalFloatAverage: 3679.928 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 14084.794 ticks.
structAverage: 11725.364 ticks.
arraySortOverloadAverage: 2186.3 ticks.
floatWithIDArray has been sorted correctly atleast once.
structArray has been sorted correctly atleast once.
arraySortOverloadArray has NOT been sorted correctly atleast once.
Press enter to exit.
```

---

**Edit 3**: I have updated the demo code once again with a fix to the overloaded method of Array.Sort. Note that I create and fill test[] outside the Stopwatch because in my case I already have that array available. arraySortOverload is faster in debug mode, and about as fast as the struct method in release mode.

New demo output (RELEASE):

```
Sorting random arrays, this will take some time...
normalFloatAverage: 2384.578 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 6405.866 ticks.
structAverage: 4583.992 ticks.
arraySortOverloadAverage: 4551.104 ticks.
floatWithIDArray has been sorted correctly all the time.
structArray has been sorted correctly all the time.
arraySortOverloadArray has been sorted correctly all the time.
Press enter to exit.
```

Comment: At a guess, it's probably because `SortTest` requires boxing and unboxing that a mere `float` doesn't need.

Comment: 1) `Array.Sort` has a high performance native code implementation for certain built in types. 2) you should also benchmark this with `SortTest` as a *struct* instead of a *class*.

Comment: If you need a float and an ID, can't you use a dictionary instead? Should be faster to sort.

Comment: I made the title a little more descriptive. I think this question highlights a common issue. Others will find the question useful as well.

Comment: As for how can you improve performance - Array.Sort has overload that take separately array of keys and values - so you can use Array.Sort(floatWithIDArray.Select(k => k.ID).ToArray(), floatWithIDArray); instead.

Comment: Your `SortStruct` doesn't implements `IComparable<T>`? Did you forgot to add it?

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar Remarkably, this is faster than just sorting an array of floats, why?

Comment: It may be faster, but the array is not actually sorted at the end.  At least, not into the same order as the float array.

Comment: You're using doubles in one test, and floats in the other.  That will mess up any speed comparisons.

Comment: @mike-of-sst You are correct, the array is not sorted correctly in the end, it's because of Linq being wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two minor ways to speed this up:

1. Use a struct instead of a class.
2. Hand-code the CompareTo() instead of using float.CompareTo().

There is also a major way to speed this up for `floatWithIDAverage`: Use x86 instead of x64. (But this does NOT speed up `normalFloatAverage`!)

**Results before making any changes (for a RELEASE build, not a DEBUG build):**

x64:

```
normalFloatAverage: 2469.86 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 6172.564 ticks.
```

x86:

```
normalFloatAverage: 3071.544 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 6036.546 ticks.
```

**Results after changing SortTest to be a struct:**

This change allows the compiler to make a number of optimizations.

x64:

```
normalFloatAverage: 2307.552 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 4214.414 ticks.
```

x86:

```
normalFloatAverage: 3054.814 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 4541.864 ticks.
```

**Results after changing SortTest.CompareTo() as follows:**

```
public int CompareTo(SortTest other)
{
    float f = other.SomeFloat;

    if (SomeFloat < f)
        return -1;
    else if (SomeFloat > f)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This change removes the overhead of calling `float.CompareTo()`.

x64:

```
normalFloatAverage: 2323.834 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 3721.254 ticks.
```

x86:

```
normalFloatAverage: 3087.314 ticks.
floatWithIDAverage: 3074.364 ticks.
```

Finally, in this specific case, `floatWithIDAverage` is actually faster than `normalFloatAverage`.

The difference between x86 and x64 is interesting!

- x64 is faster than x86 for `normalFloatAverage`
- x86 is faster than x64 for `floatWithIDAverage`

**Conclusion**

Although I can't explain why the x86 version is so much faster than the x64 version for `floatWithIDAverage`,  I have shown a way of speeding it up significantly.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, as I am not getting the same results in RELEASE mode, or any other configuration.

Comment: @ManIkWeet Are you running it by using "Debug | Start without debugging" (or pressing Ctrl+F5)? Also, are you using .Net 4.5x?

Comment: @ManIkWeet Also, use `Random random = new Random(12345);` instead of `Random random = new Random();` otherwise consecutive runs will be doing different sorts which can distort the results.

Comment: Your implementation of `CompareTo` doesn't work with `NaN`s. Probably won't matter for the OP.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was changing the configuration manager. I am using Visual Studio 2012 so that should be .NET 4.5

Comment: @CodesInChaos True, I'll add an implementation for completeness.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Indeed, NaN does not happen in my case.

Comment: I changed my mind and won't add the implementation that supports NaN because if you do so, it runs the same speed as just calling float.CompareTo()!

Comment: @MatthewWatson It could be processor related then, my processor is an old Core 2 Duo E8400 :)

Comment: @ManIkWeet That might be it - I have a quad core with hyperthreading thingy. Also, just be completely clear: Are you starting the program via "Debug | Start without debugging" or are you just pressing F5?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Negligible differences:
  
    normalFloatAverage: 2398.37 ticks.  
    floatWithIDAverage: 5419.712 ticks.  
    structAverage: 4196.372 ticks.  
    arraySortOverloadAverage: 4536.972 ticks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll complement the other answers by adding another way to optimize this. Using a struct certainly is essential. It removes lots of pointer following and makes the JIT generate specialized generics code just for this struct.

The JIT is unfortunately sometimes not able to completely remove all generics overhead even when you use a struct. For that reason it can be beneficial to fork the .NET `Array.Sort` code and hard-code your array item type. This is a brutal thing to do. It's only worth it if your performance requirements are high. I have done this once and it payed off.

Comment: My performance requirements are not THAT high, thankfully. I just want it to sort in 0.04 milliseconds instead of 2-3 milliseconds.

Comment: That's 50x speedup. You're never going to reach that. Not even with this trick. But this might buy you 2x. Cloning 100 lines or so is not *too* bad.